# how to share dev-dependencies between Python projects within the same monorepo?

Tags: python, monorepo, python-poetry

I have two monorepos like this:

```sh
.
├── monorepo1/
│   ├── apps/
│   │   ├── app1/
│   │   └── app2/
│   └── libs/
│       ├── lib1/
│       └── lib2/
└── monorepo2/
    ├── apps/
    │   ├── app3/
    │   └── app4/
    └── libs/
        ├── lib3/
        └── lib4/
```

Each monorepo contains `apps` and `libs` which contains python packages.

I want to share **dev-dependencies** for the same monorepo, but I did not find a way to do that. I'm using **Poetry** to manage Python package dependencies.

- Using `poetry add -D` will only install **dev-dependencies** in that Python package (e.g.e `app1`).
- Installing packages as **global packages** will influence other monorepos.

How could I install dev-dependencies once for all in a monorepo1?

Additionally, I'm using **VSCode**, and setting `settings.json` for each python project to use its own python env. For example:

```json
// monorepo1/apps/app1/.vscode/settings.json
{
  "python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python",
}
```

How could I make it possible to find monorepo's **dev-dependencies** (e.g. `pytest` / `pylint` / `black` / `ipykernel`...) without installing those dev-dependencies for each python project within the same monorepo?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. poetry's philosophy is to separate each project. But there are some thoughts about how to support subpackages. See https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2270

Comment: Does that mean I need to install the same dev dependencies multiple times with multiple sub-projects? Is it possible to use symbolic links for dev dependencies to eliminate the unnecessary duplicated installations?

Comment: No, every package will have it's own virtual environment. Including all the dev dependencies. You'll need to let the virtual environment (conda / virtualenv / ..) optimize you disk space.

Comment: Regarding installing the same (version of) dev dependencies in all apps/libs:
you could create an extra `dev-tools` package, which has the develpment dependencies of your choice (`mypy` and the like) as production (main) dependencies. Then add that `dev-tools` package as a **dev** dependency to all your projects.